# SwissGap savings platform, is it legit or scam?

Tags: scams, savings-account

Recently I found this ad for something called called SwissGap.

They promise very high returns like 5% a month on 1000 USD investment for their savings account.
So I registered and got called by one of their account managers I guess, who was eagerly trying to make me deposit my first funds already, without letting me properly reading the contract provided in their platform or doing any verification of documents.
But it really started to smell fishy when the deposit she suggested to do was via cryptocurrency medium changeally. So basically I should buy USDT and send it to my swissgap account. I postponed the call and want to checkout if anybody has any idea.

So anybody familiar with them?

Comment: I have never heard of these people before, but your description sounds very dubious - a) exceptionally high returns; b) pushing you to transfer money immediately; c) involves transferring funds by cryptocurrency. I would not proceed any further with this if I were you.

Comment: in addition, d) they have four Trustpilot reviews, all four from people who have never reviewed anything else; e) their quoted phone number is +46, Swedish, but their (claimed) address is Swiss; and f) their website was created three months ago. Each of these is a red flag, and all together...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the asker is linking directly to a scam site, and attempting to show it as being real by linking to clearly-dubious reviews.

Comment: In all honesty I’m not attempting to show any integrity of the scam. In fact I refused to continue with them after doing some more research and this question was part of that research. So thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Risk and reward go hand in hand.
If I want zero risk, I can get a fraction of a percent annual return currently.
Long term, 10% per year (The US stock market) comes with a standard deviation of 17-18%, but in rolling periods that are greater than one year, STDEV drops.

To get "as much as 5%/mo" must bring a high level of risk. The FAQ on their site says it all, which is close to nothing. I'd walk away. If you decide not to, please visit in a few months and update us.

Comment: For fun, I recently attended an options webinar.  They want $400 a month for their "basic service", offering that you'll make 2-5% a month. If you don't make money in the first year, they'll refund 1/2 of the cost. That's a nice annuity.   I gotta stop providing answers for free and get into this online mentor business ;->)

Comment: That certainly sounds less sketchy than straight-up asking for $2400 :)

Comment: For my own curiosity, is there a certain source where you calculated that standard deviation from?

Comment: @Flats - The numbers are easy to search for, but the results are all over the place. In any given year, volatility can change. I look at [MoneyChimp](http://www.moneychimp.com/features/market_cagr.htm) as one source of data.

Answer (score 12):

Telling you an investment earns 5% per month = scam. No other discussion necessary. Nothing earns that much without being gambling or a lie.

Answer (score 1):

Swissgap is a scam investment company they have scammed of my £200. Since they took my money their phone numbers don't go through anymore try to contact them on several occasions including too their so called representative in the UK called Andrew and his phone number is no longer in use.